# How does Module.parameters() find the parameters?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I noticed that whenever you create a new net extending `torch.nn.Module`, you can immediately call `net.parameters()` to find the parameters relevant for backpropagation.

```
import torch

class MyNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc = torch.nn.Linear(5, 5)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.fc(x)

net = MyNet()
print(list(net.parameters()))
```

But then I wondered, how is this even possible? I just assigned this `Linear` layer object to a member variable but it is not recorded anywhere else (or is it?). Somehow `MyNet` must be able to keep track of the parameters used but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple really, just go through attributes via meta-programming and check their type

```
class Example():
    def __init__(self):
        self.special_thing = nn.Parameter(torch.rand(2))
        self.something_else = "ok"

    def get_parameters(self):
        for key, value in self.__dict__.items():
            if type(value) == nn.Parameter:
                print(key, "is a parameter!")


e = Example()
e.get_parameters()
# => special_thing is a parameter!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this clear and concise answer, I was not aware of the meta-programming capabilities of python at all!